# How to access the photo from the library in iPad?

Tags: ipad, photo-gallery

I want to access the iPad photo library and retrieve the image and display it in a image-view.

Answer (score 1):

use Assets Library Framework

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/07/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for help with the UIImagePickerController?

http://trailsinthesand.com/picking-images-with-the-iphone-sdk-uiimagepickercontroller/

Comment: This will work in iphone but not in ipad.I want to know for ipad.

Answer (score 0):

The iPad equivalent of an UIImagePickerController is a UIPopoverController. This YouTube video shows a basic implementation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaaLMKuPwfU. I just added a check so that only one Popover is present at a time; see         `if (pop.isPopoverVisible == TRUE)` below. And the video shows how to connect up the button using Interface Builder. (And obviously, you'll need images on your device or simulator for this to work.) Hope it helps.

**The header file**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{    
}
- (IBAction)barBtn1:(id)sender;

@end
```

**The implementation file**:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@implementation MyViewController

- (IBAction)barBtn1:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];

    // If user selects button while previous pop is visible, dismiss previous pop.
    if (pop.isPopoverVisible == TRUE)
    {
        [pop dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
    [pop setDelegate:self];
    [pop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    [imagePicker release];
}
```